# Warning: Attempt to present "Stream Scene" on "Web Scene whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6

4 and Swift.
I get this error Warning: Attempt to present "" whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

[image]

When i modally present my Stream Scene. 
When i start up the app and navigate from "Web" to "Stream" everything work as it should. If something is true in "Stream" i use

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Web", sender: self)
```

to go back to "Web". The same i do in "Web" if something is true there i use

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Stream", sender: self)
```

to navigate to "Stream. Everything works at it should when i start up the app and navigate to "Stream" from "Web", but when i go back from "Stream" to "Web" and then navigate from "Web" to "Stream" again I get this error - and everything is not working at it does first time. I don't think I'm doing it right when it comes to navigate through views?

Comment: My whole project? @DharmeshKheni

Comment: I'll like you to take a look at it - i have been struggle with this issue for too long. How can i send you my project in a zip-file? @DharmeshKheni

Comment: okay - ill give you a download link to dropbox as soon at it is there.

Comment: I have sent and mailto you @DharmeshKheni

Comment: DO you have any clue why @Dharmeshkheni